# Transient Spice Simulation of Flyback Converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

I have created a simple model of a flyback converter using the PWM switch model by Vatche Vorperian. The simulation should be transient showing the switch events. In the picture below you see the Schematic and Simulation output of V(out) and V(Switch) node. There is quite a high voltage spike over the primary winding, which I guess is caused by parasitic inductance of diode, which acts as stray inductance. This is causing the output voltage to be lower than expected (19.5V).
How can I avoid this spike?

[image]

Comment: You are making a classic mistake: you have used an *averaged* model, the PWM switch. This model is used to obtain a frequency response. There is no switching component and what you can simulate are averaged transient results. No switching effects beside simulation artifacts. If you want to check voltage and current waveforms, you will have to resort to a cycle-by-cycle model. There are plenty of examples in Microcap but you could also try one of the 60+ SIMPLIS [templates](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) that I built.

Comment: This clarifies a lot! I have seen your Microcap examples and was wondering why they are always average models. So it appears when I want to check actual switching waveforms, I will need go with switches or FET models. Would like to use SIMPLIS, but it's too expensive for my personal projects.

Comment: I think they converted many of my models in averaged but also switched versions with the generic PWM controller I made. Regarding SIMPLIS, most of the examples I posted on my page simulate with the free demo version Elements: you can already do a lot.

Comment: I will check it out. Do you by any change also have a simulation for flyback converter with aux winding and primary side regulation? (I am still working on the converter we wrote over email about a year ago)